# Create a spline function to interpolate a 3D surface

Tags: fitting, interpolation, splines

Here's my problem, I have an spreadsheet that contains data, a 202x202 matrix with x,y and z coordinates. The objective is import the data to mathematica, and then I need to create an interpolation function (cubic) from scratch to interpolate the entire surface. My problem is to create the entire spline function starting from scratch, and then map it across the surface. If anyone as a clue, I'll be happy to hear it !

PS : the points of the surface are experimental values

Answer (score 3):

You are asking about many steps without showing any code, so I think an equally high-level answer is appropriate.

Use:

- [`Import`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html) to import data.
- [`ListInterpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListInterpolation.html) with [`InterpolationOrder`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolationOrder.html) set to 3 create a cubic [`InterpolatingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html).

I don't understand what "map it across the surface" means.

Comment: I already imported the data. What I need to do is create the interpolating function, I cannot use built-in functions. The problem is that I know how to create a spline for a f(x) function, but I don't know how to do it for a f(x,y). I already searched bicubic interpolation algorithms but I still don't get how to program it with mathematica.